# affects on output when different sets are used in java

Tags: set

```
    import java.util.*; 
public class Example { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
// insert code here 
set.add(new Integer(2)); 
set.add(new Integer(1)); 
System.out.println(set); 
} 
} 


         Set set = new TreeSet(); 
         Set set = new HashSet(); 
         Set set = new SortedSet(); 
         List set = new SortedList(); 
         Set set = new LinkedHashSet();
```

this question was in ocjp please help me with it
Which code, inserted at line 4, guarantees that this program will output [1, 2]?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is  `Set set = new TreeSet();`

For all Wrapper classes, Treeset defines one natural ordering using Comparable interface. So it will automatically sort the integers.